# How to select all elements with a specific attribute in a page with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Imagine that I have this html code:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="test">
        <a class="test1" href="#">test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am writing some codes for a.test1 in a .js file.I may have more that 6 or 7 div.test in a page.I want to select one all of them and change their class.
Let me show my .js content:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $(".test1").live("click", function () {
        //Its where I want to select all div.test in the page
    });
});
```

Now.How to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Why not use $( '.test' ).addClass( "className" ) inside the click handler?

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
$('div.test').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('testClass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, if the `.test1` elements are in the HTML when it's loaded:

```
$('.test1').on('click', function () {
    $('div.test').toggleClass('oldClassToRemove newClassToAdd');
});
```

Or, if they're added to the `div.test` elements afterwards (and therefore after the events are bound):

```
$('div.test').on('click', '.test1', function () {
    $('.test').toggleClass('oldClassToRemove newClassToAdd');
});
```

Note that, as of jQuery 1.7 `live()` was deprecated and, as of jQuery 1.9, removed from the jQuery library; and in jQuery earlier than 1.7 `delegate()` is recommended, rather than `live()`.

Comparable approach using `delegate()`:

```
$('div.test').delegate('.test1', 'click', function () {
    $('.test').toggleClass('oldClassToRemove newClassToAdd');
});
```

References:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
jQuery(".test1").click(function() {
  // Do something there
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2R74G/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for adding information, noone mentioned http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ where explain you every single way to select any element/elements in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
  $(document).on("click","a.test1", function () {

   $('div.test').removeClass('test').addClass('newClass');

  });
});
```

Or

```
$("document").ready(function () {
  $(document).on("click","a.test1", function () {

   $('div.test').attr('class', 'newClass');

  });
});
```